# 'maybe not us' or 'maybe not we'

Tags: pronouns, syntax

(from Seinfeld)

> -- We could build a cabin like that.
>
> -- Well, maybe not **us**, but two men could.

I would use **we** instead of **us**. Is **us** here grammatically correct?

Comment: This is a good question.   I can tell you that *us* is the accepted choice here and that *we* doesn't work. I can also tell you that "Well, maybe **we** couldn't" is also correct, but I can't tell you why.

Comment: The accusative "us" is the more natural choice. And **Seinfeld** agrees with us.

Comment: Quite opposite to Jim's comment, I think *we* works better. Who built a cabin like that? **We (not Us) did!** Not only that, while renaming the subject, we use subject pronoun. For example: It is ***we*** who are responsible for this mess. Anyway  +1

Comment: @MaulikV- *we* works generally, but *not* with "not us" and I see you've come to that realization too, given your deleted answer.

Comment: "Us" is the correct choice. _"We"_ fits better in contexts where you have a sort of Q&A, like in the examples pointed out by @MaulikV, but _"us"_ fits in descriptive sentences like in OP's example. There is a very subtle difference that's very easy to miss.

Comment: @Jim Yes, you are right! :) Finding it difficult to come up with *not us* But I'll try.

Comment: Perhaps this post might have some related info for you: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31639/not-they-or-not-them/31680#31680 -- notice example [14.i] and the discussion related to it.

Comment: From both of these questions, I feel rule must be different for 1st person. For 2nd or 3rd person, it is Subject form that is used, for 1st, an Object is considered correct.

Comment: @F.E.: Probably in English you can not say "maybe not we" at all; you must say "**maybe** this statement is **not** about **us**" and then you are allowed to contract it to "**maybe not us**".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Us" is more idiomatic. Consider this sentence:

> He asked three people to dinner, but he didn't ask me.

"Me" is in the accusative here, because it's the object of the verb "to ask."

The sentence you're asking about is, in essence the same sentence. You are approaching it as if the full sentence represented by "not us" would be something like "Us couldn't build it." In fact, the whole sentence would more likely be unpacked something like this:

> Well, not us, but two men could.
>
> Two men could, but not us.
>
> Two men could build it, but not us.
>
> Two men could build it, but those two men are not us.

My theory is that "us" is accurate because this is an implied parallel construction, and the subject of both halves is "two men." So you would use the accusative just as you would in any other parallel construction:

> I like her, but not him.

If the subject or verb was included, it would eliminate any ambiguity, and in that case, with the appropriate addition, either "us" or "we" would be idiomatic:

> Two men could, but we **couldn't**.
>
> Two men could, but **they're** not us.

Comment: Your examples "he didn't ask me" and "I like her but not him" aren't parallel, because "me" and "him" are clearly the objects of "ask" and "like" respectively. It's not so clear-cut whether the verb "to be" takes nominative or accusative for its objects (consider "I am he" or "it was I who stole your money") and I think you need to address that directly.

Answer (score 0):

> “Why not we”

is grammatically correct, though uncommon in general usage.  Using ‘we’ in the above construct is **no different** than

> “Why couldn’t we?”

One **wouldn’t** say

> “Why couldn’t us ...(do that). “